# How to align Text properly in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, text-alignment

I actually want to find out how I can center text in a button correctly. I am using a custom font and with this font, it won't center my text inside of the button no matter what I am doing.

I already have found out, that with the standard Font (I guess its Roboto) it's not aligning perfectly in the center too but this isn't very annoying at that point.

Here is my code:

```
RaisedButton(
   onPressed: () {},
   child: Text("LOG IN"),
),
```

Here what it produces with my custom font:

[image]

And here with standard Roboto:

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: what font are you using, it might be the issue but we need to make sure.

Comment: Yes, I tried a few other fonts and it seems to be only the case with this font. It's a private font from a customer but its similar to Secca, or I think its Secca with a few tweaks. I don't know exactly.

Comment: seems good, you can still kinda center it by adding a wrapping the text in a Column and adding a SizedBox above it and try as much as you can to center, even though I recommend switching fonts. if you don't know you can check https://fonts.google.com/ (Google  Fonts) for some good stable fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add padding 0

```
RaisedButton(
   padding: EdgeInsets.all(0), //<- try add this
   onPressed: () {},
   child: Text("LOG IN"),
),
```

Comment: also does nothing sadly

Comment: @Noah-YannickSchmid so there must be something wrong with the font.. Can you share  picture with debug paint? If you use android studio then go to 'Flutter inspector' and click on 'Show debug paint' (blue icon with 4 arrows)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Center()` widget to see what happen

```
RaisedButton(
   onPressed: () {},
   child: Center(child: Text("LOG IN")),
),
```

Comment: isn't that gonna make the button take the whole space, I tried it as the only child of Scaffold body and it took the whole screen

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried that but it won't change the result, except of the button being stretched horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

If the alignment changes from one font to another it's unlikely to be a padding or flutter related alignment issue as suggested in the other answers.

This can be caused by using a font format that's not properly supported by flutter/android/ios, e.g. I had this exact issue using a font in oft format and using the ttf version fixed it.

This thread from some time ago highlights that this is not properly documented and other formats such as woff2 are also not supported: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13823